# Multinomial theorem with multivariate terms?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multinomial-theorem

Let $S=\{a,b,c,d,...\}$. Let $P_n=(abc+abd+acd+...+ab+ac+ad+...a+b+c+d...)^n$. In addition, there's the condition that for all variables, $x^n=x$ (maybe it'll be easier without this?).  Is there something like the multinomial theorem to expand out $P_n$?

Edit: Here's what I have so far: For any $n$, the unique terms in the expanded product is the set of terms $a^{k_1}b^{k_2}c^{k_3}...$, such that $k_1,k_2,k_3,... \le n$ (you can have at most $n$ multiplicands in the product), and that $n \le k_1+k_2+k_3+... \le 3n$ (at minimum, there are $n$ length-1 multiplicands in the product, and at most, there are $n$ length-3 multiplicands in the product).
For any such term $a^{k_1}b^{k_2}c^{k_3}...$, to find the number of terms that make it up, there must be $k_1$ terms that have $a$, $k_2$ terms that includes $b$, $k_3$ that includes c, and so on.

Edit 2: I realize that this can be done recursively --- for a given term, remove one of the original terms ($abc, abd, ...$), and find the composition of that smaller term,

Comment: Why can't you apply the multinomial theorem directly?

Comment: It wouldn't allow me to combine like terms.

Comment: What kind of terms are included in $P_n$? For example, if $S=\{a,b,c\}$, is $P_n$ given by $$P_n=(abc+ab+bc+ca+a+b+c+1)^n\quad ?$$ As it is written, it is not entirely clear as to how $P_n$ is defined.

Comment: @SangchulLee Close, remove the $1$.